# httpClient get request getting 404 not found response

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, xmlhttprequest, httpclient

I have migrated the project form angular version 5.1 to 8, after this some of the api calls which were using http as been changed to httpClient,but once we start the  project the 1st call to service layer getting as 404 not found, the call is not hitting the service layer , below is my code

```js
const routes: Routes = [
 {
  path: '',
  component: MasterComponent,
  resolve: { "appUser": CheckAccessService },
  children: [
   {
    matcher: ReadFinder,
    loadChildren: () => import('app/Read-Finder/read-finder.module').then(m => m.ReadFinderModule),
    canLoad: [CheckAccessService],
    canActivateChild: [CheckAccessService]
   },
   ----------------
      --------------
     ]
   },
   {
  path: '',
  component: MasterPageComponent,
  resolve: { "appUser": CheckAccessService },
  children: [
   { path: 'NoAuthorityPage', component: NoAuthorityPageComponent },
   { path: '**', component: PageNotFound },
  ]
 }, 
];
```

and in CheckAccessService the code for resolve look like this,

```js
@Injectable()
export class CheckAccessService  implements Resolve<UserInfo>, CanLoad, CanActivate, CanActivateChild {
   resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<UserInfo> {
  
  let url = window.location.pathname;
  let _url = url.startsWith('/') ? url.substring(1) : url;
  return new Observable<UserInfo>((subscriber: Subscriber<UserInfo>) => {
   if (this.userInfo) {
    subscriber.next(this.getCachedUserInfo());
    subscriber.complete();
    return;
   }
   this.navApiService.getUserInfo()
    .subscribe(
    user => {
     this.storeUserInfo(user);
     setTimeout(() => {
      subscriber.next(user);
      subscriber.complete();
     });
    },
    err => {
     this.storeUserInfo(null);
     //clear session storage for unlogged users
     window.sessionStorage.clear();
     setTimeout(() => {
      this.redirectOnFail(url, err.status === 403);
     }, 3000);
    }
    )
  });
 }



}
```

in resolve method we have a api call, which is the 1st call from the application to server , it look like this,

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

 constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }
 getUserInfo(): Observable<UserInfoData> {
  return this.http.get('/api/security/user-info')
   .map(resp => <UserInfoData>resp)
   .catch(err => {
    return observableThrowError(err);
   });
 }
}
```

and the error in chrome look like this,

[image]

Comment: Have you check  your back end server is running on `localhost:4200`? Or something else?

Answer (score -1):

Friend!

First of all, I am worried about my English, I find myself with the same problem when it comes to updating my version of Angular to 8,
I was using http, but with version 8 it was obsolete and I had to migrate all the services to HttpClienr.
Try updating your version of angular to version 7. For my case it went.
Regards!